# Valuation of players across uneven games

Tags: mathematical-statistics, ranking, games

I have a 'portfolio' of players that I need to evaluate and compare across many games. There is a common metric,let's call it value, I am using to evaluate a players performance in a single game.

**However, not every player plays in each game and not every game has the same weight across players when computing value (i.e. the amount and weight of data points vary)**.

What is the best way to rank each players value across all games?

For example we might have something like this (in my case m is much bigger than n):

[image: Example]

Comment: You should consider the literature on pairwise comparisons.  I am puzzled by the numbers and the "NA" symbol.  Where do you show the individual players' game scores?

Comment: @michaelchernic In this example a players score for a specific game is the number at the intersection of player and game. NA  implies that a player did not play in a particular game.

Comment: Just off-the-cuff, I wonder if 1. centering and scaling across rows excluding NA's, and 2. averaging each column could do the trick. Try it out, and take a critical look at the results, knowing what you know about the subject matter.